# Prestashop Productcomments Module Issue

Tags: prestashop

I am experiencing a problem with the Productcomments module which I am using in a custom module and I cannot figure out how to fix it. The problem is with the star rating in the Productcomments form itself. This form works perfectly in a localhost environment - see images 1 and 2, but not on a live server - see images 3 and 4. On the live server it is showing no stars, just radio buttons, and no delete button for removing the stars.

[Form as it looks on WAMP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWind.jpg)

[Code from Chromes Inspect for WAMP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plA6m.jpg)

[Form as it looks on Live Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FviCW.jpg)

[Code from Chromes Inspect for Live Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAKb5.jpg)

Disabling the link to the following 2 js files recreates the problem on the local server which would suggest that the problem lies in the links to these two files on the live server, however I have checked all links to these files and they are correct, as are the permissions for these files.

**jquery.rating.pack.js** and **productcomments.js**

Occasionally when I clear cache under Advanced Parameters > Performance I get the following error message:

**Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: unable to write file /home/productm/public_html/cache/smarty/compile/10/e2/20/wrt5cbbb0747109d3_91450142
<-- thrown in /home/productm/public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_write_file.php on line 46**

This problem applies to all 1.6 versions of Prestashop tested.

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem would be appreciated.

Thanks

Kathleen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix erorr "Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: unable to write file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631249/how-to-fix-erorr-fatal-error-uncaught-smarty-unable-to-write-file)

Answer (score -1):

*The error code you've got from clearing cache is linked to permission problems.
Here's probably a duplicate of your issue: [How to fix erorr "Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: unable to write file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631249/how-to-fix-erorr-fatal-error-uncaught-smarty-unable-to-write-file)
Check that your prestashop files are set to 644 and folders 755 permission. (not just the js files you've mentioned).
Also if you manually moved the module to your live server(ftp), check the ownership of those files.*

Edit:
I'll add this to the answer since the permissions didn't fix your problem.

looks like you have a prestashop bug going on with the JS (Synchronous loaded scripts)

here's a patch to fix that, maybe it fixes your original problem.
https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/pull/6749/commits/73fd8dbed9f413a70f7d04fc4badd48f00ca501a

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already checked on the permissions and they are correct. I will check out the link you have supplied. I'll keep you informed. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any JS errors/warnings in your developer console on live server?

Comment: Firstly, I can tell you that the above error message has nothing to do with this problem, it relates to another issue which I have fixed. I cannot for certain say it isn't a permission thing but I cannot find it. The only error in the Console is: 
jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: I've edited my answer according to your Console error, hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep you informed.

Comment: Unfortunately, the versions I have have already had the bug fixed. I am receiving the following errors in Firefox:Source map error: request failed with status 404
Source Map URL: productcomments.css.map[Learn More]

Source map error: request failed with status 404
Source Map URL: global.css.map[Learn More]

Comment: i'm sorry my solutions didn't provide you a fix, is your store public so i could take a look?

Comment: Hello yasoh, I am working on one other possibility to fix this problem. If it fails I am happy for you to take a look. Can you provide me with an email address so I can give you the store URL?

Comment: Hello yasoh, I have sent you an email with url details. I still cannot fix this problem. It seems that the js files are not loading. You will read more in the email.  Thanks aussiecomet

Comment: Hello yasoh, Please disregard my email. The problem has been fixed. It was in the links in setMedia. Instead of using $this->context->controller->addJS(dirname(__FILE__), I had to use $this->context->controller->addJS(_PS_MODULE_DIR_. Thanks.